# "repositories" under "local" in "Github for Windows" did not show all local repositories

Tags: github

I have installed "Github for Windows" in my Windows 7 Home Premium.

The question is:

When I use this application, in the left, there are two labels "local" and "github", when I select "repositories" under "local", there are only 4 repositories listed, but actually under directory: C:\Users\myname\git, there are 20 local repositories. (4 of them shown, but 16 did not)

So how can bring these 16 repositories to show in "repositories" under "local" in "Github for Windows", so that I can open a shell for selected repository, and have some operations on it?

(I have tried to uninstall and reinstall "Github for Windows", but it still shows 4 local repositories; I usually use EClipse to commit/fetch/push)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have 16 "repositories" or are they just normal directories? You need to do a git init in the directory for it to become a git repo.

Comment: Thanks @cen for your reply. I have one Eclipse (version Kepler) which have 9 repositories, another Eclipse (Galileo) with 3 workspaces (each with different number of local repositories), all together will be 20.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question....

But I was able to "drag" the missing folders from the explorer window into the GitHub window and they appeared.